# How to get the JSON fields and values in the controller?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

The client sends the following JSON:

```
 {"User": {"name": "Jhon", "nationality", "brazilian", "gender": "male"}}
```

How can I get the JSON and each field and value individually for use in the controller and ecto query?

*Automatically translated.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able use `conn.params` like so:

`conn.params["User"]`, `conn.params["User"]["gender"]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

use elixir poison: https://github.com/devinus/poison

Then use:

```
Poison.decode!(~s({"User": {"name": "Jhon", "nationality", "brazilian", "gender": "male"}}), as: %User{})
```